# Hiding Google recaptcha badge via CSS and displaying the legal text instead?

Tags: css, recaptcha, captcha, invisible-recaptcha

We are using the current CSS to remove the Google recaptcha badge on our site:

```
<style>
    .grecaptcha-badge { 
        visibility: hidden; 
    }
</style>
```

This now sees a blank space, as expected, where the ReCaptcha badge was prior on various pages. I'm interested what the easiest way would be to modify this code above, whilst keeping the recaptcha badge invisible and to instead display the legal text in that empty space which is:

```
<small>This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google
    <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
    <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms">Terms of Service</a> apply.
</small>
```

Comment: I don't recommend to change the captcha via javascript to keep it functioning properly.
You could add the text to the website itself, wether in the footer or as a box styled to look like a reCaptcha and just keep the captcha badge hidden.

Answer (score 2):

To hide REcaptcha V3 from all browsers, add this to your custom CSS :

```css
.rc-anchor-normal-footer {
    display: none !important;
}
.grecaptcha-badge { 
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```